# How to develop $f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$ into a power series?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I tried to develop the following
$f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$

into a power series. However, I was not able to do that. Since I tried to split it into two fractions, and it didn't work neither for me or when  [Trying](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial%20fraction%20decomposition%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ApartCalculator%22%2C%20%22rationalfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%2F%282%2Bx%29%5E2%22) on Wolfram, I am stuck.

So then I tried computing the power series by the following procedure:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}=-\left(h(x)\right)^2\\
h(x)=\frac{1}{x+2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^n\\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}x^n\\
f(x)=-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}x^n\right)^2
\end{equation}

But from here I am stuck.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139254/discussion-on-question-by-luthier415hz-how-to-develop-fx-frac1x22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to write series...I suppose a Maclaurin series, around $\;x=0\;$ . Then you can go as follows:

$$-\frac1{(x+2)^2}=\left(\frac1{x+2}\right)'=\frac12\left(\frac1{1+\frac x2}\right)'=\left[\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac x2\right)^n\right]'=\ldots$$

continue...and remember a power series can be termwise differentiated within its convergence interval...

Answer (score 2):

Since your OP completely changed, your new question needs a new answer.

Your idea was good! Persevere:

$$f(x)=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}x^k\right)^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
with
$$a_n=-\sum_{i+j=n\;(i,j\in\mathbb N)}\frac{(-1)^i}{2^{i+1}}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^{j+1}}
=-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+2}}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{2^{n+2}}.$$
The keyword is [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: Thanks Anne! It is always nice to see constructive pedagogics! I will study your solution next week.